# why does not return a value?

Tags: android, arraylist, return

Why this method does not return data? I do not understand. 
I can print the data in the loop, but does not return data. 
Thank you in advance.

public static ArrayList getNewspapers(final Context context,String name) {

```
    final ArrayList<String> newspapersList = new ArrayList<String>();

    AsyncHttpClient cli = new AsyncHttpClient();
    cli.get("http://brnbyk.com/newspapers/islemler.php?islem=ulkebul&keyword="
            +name, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String content) {

            try {

                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(content);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    newspapersList.add(jo.getString("adi"));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return newspapersList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your AsyncHttpClient is creating a thread running in the background. This however causes your function to return without waiting for the callback to store the retrieved data in the result list. The result is an empty list being returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's an asynchronous call, to not block the UI thread. You get the result of your operation in the onSuccess callback, but at the moment of return your arraylist is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

write the code inside a finally block.
after try block the  codes in finally will execute even there is an exception.

[image]